# Does PayPal still support activity report and balance via HTTP REST API?

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

thanks for reading - my questions are simple:

- What am I doing wrong?
- What am I missing?
- Do I need to additional access to make use of the report engine?

I cannot seem to obtain balance or transaction data from my pp account using a simple python client despite what appears to be correct use of documented APIs.

I have:

- a business account
- dev portal access
- valid creds for a Sandbox and Live API use

My py client wraps a few API calls and successfully completes the following:

- obtain API token using dev portal creds
- use API token to make valid HTTP requests to the balances and transactions API resources
- API responses indicate 200 OK

However, except for the OAuth token request, all of the responses all say *Empty XML data*

Pseudo-sample code

```
# -- pp_auth_header is a global, contains Auth Bearer token

def get_balances():
    print("get_balances...")

    headers = pp_auth_header

    endpoint = "/v1/reporting/balances"
    query = "?currency_code=USD&as_of_time=2021-02-22T00:00:00-0700"

    r = requests.get(pp_report_eng_url + endpoint + query, headers=pp_auth_header)

    print("get_balances - status: {}".format(r.status_code))

    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("get_balances - r.text: {}".format(r.text))

# -- output of the above is

get_balances...
get_balances - url: https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/balances?currency_code=USD&as_of_time=2021-02-22T00:00:00-0700
get_balances - status: 200
get_balances - r.text: Empty XML data
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate an acess_token and then test from the command line with curl, [as documented](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/transaction-search/#check-balances):

```sh
curl -v -X GET
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/balances?currency_code=USD&as_of_time=2016-10-15T06:07:00-0700
\
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

Ensure you pass the headers described there, including "Content-Type: application/json".

PayPal REST APIs do not return XML.

If this doesn't work, post the output of that curl -v command as well as the scopes returned by the oauth2 token request. Update your question with those details.